# Set IntelliJ refactoring and code completion to insert `this` before class fields?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, autocomplete, this, code-completion

To prevent accidental shadowing, I use `this.` before class fields as standard practice. I would like my IntelliJ to follow this same convention when autocompleting, generating, or inserting code. This feels like something the editor should be able to do. Where is this setting, and how do I configure it?

If this is not already a built-in feature, is there an existing plug-in that will accomplish the same goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid IDEA cannot to exactly what you want (out of the box). The best you can do is to go to `Settings -> Editor -> Inspections -> Java -> Code style issues` and enable `Instance field access not qualified with this` inspection. After you enable the inspection, IDEA will start highlighting all unqualified accesses to fields in your Java files. Then fixing all such accesses will be very easy: you just press `Alt+Enter` on any unqualified access, select `Cleanup Code` and IDEA will add `this.` where necessary. Also, you can click `Analyze -> Silent Code Cleanup` at any time, it will add `this.` too.